# How to unzip or uncompress a file .epub on Drupal?

Tags: nodes, files

I've created a content type that upload files .epub on database. Now for some reason (to use epub on a mobile app) I need to get the file .epub uncompressed.

It's like in my content type I upload a .zip file but when drupal store it it's stored unzipped.

Did someone knows a Drupal API function or a method that uncompress or unzip a .epub files?

Note that when I upload an .epub file or .jpg image or any other type of extensions, in the table file_managed I always get filemime : "application/octet-stream"? is it normal ?

Comment: Is this functionality to be exposed exposed to a moderated and manged group of users, or to anonymous users as well?

Comment: Hi, the upload of an .epub is done by the admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP already has a built in class to process zip files. You can combine that with a [`hook_node_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) invocation in a custom module to process the field containing your ePub file and extract it to a directory in your file system.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  if(isset($node->field_MYFIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'])) {
    $file = file_load($node->field_sss[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid']);
    $file_path = drupal_realpath($file->uri);
    $file_name = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($file_path)) {
      $zip->extractTo(drupal_realpath("public://MYMODULE_customdir/$file_name"));
      $zip->close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tested it, it's all that that i wanted Shawn, thank you again !